# Dynamically set class or style on button using Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a button that may require a class to be applied ..

```
<button ion-button color="dark" [ngClass]='getJobClasses(job)' (click)="changeStatus(job.jobID)" outline>{{ job.jobName }}</button>
```

The getJobClasses function is:

```
getJobClasses(job) {
    if(job.hasJob == 1) {
        return {
            ['job-block-enabled'] : job.hasJob == 1
        }
    }
}
```

So, if `job.hasJob = 1` then the class `job-block-enabled` is applied to the button. Otherwise this class isn't set.

This works well.

What I would like to do is expand the functionality here and say:

1. If `job.hasJob=1` then add the class job-block-enabled
2. Otherwise, if `job.categoryDefault` is set then apply the style `background-color: job.categoryDefault`
3. Otherwise apply no style and set no background color

It seems like this is complicated as I need to apply either a class or a style depending on the values within job

Comment: Why not simplify it and do everything using `ngClass` or `ngStyle`?

Comment: That's my option if there is no relatively straight forward way to achieve what I need. I am trying to be a little lazy and avoid reformating parts of the backend to make it all work with classes